# Lowest Common Ancestors (LCAS) of multiple nodes in a directed graph?

Tags: java, graph, lowest-common-ancestor

I am interested in calculating the lowest common ancestors of several nodes in a directed graph. I tested the findlcas method proposed by the NaiveLcaFinder class of the jGrapht project (https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/blob/master/jgrapht-core/src/main/java/org/jgrapht/alg/NaiveLcaFinder.java) but I found it very difficult to apply it for several nodes. Could you please help me on this point? or give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

See this, it is from `Bio4J` but has a pretty good explanation and might help you to figure your solution out:
[Taxonomy algorithm](http://bio4j.com/blog/2012/02/finding-the-lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-set-of-ncbi-taxonomy-nodes-with-bio4j/)